# AWS Amplify error on sign in: <could not find 'Data'. the token is not a base64 encoded string>

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, multi-factor-authentication

We have our backend made in AWS and using AWS Amplify in our iOS App for login/signup, API calls, storage access. We have enabled MFA(Multi-factor  Authentication) for the signing in/up the users. The signup process is as follows:

1. We let the user enter his phone number, email, and password for signing up. (signup API call)
2. User receives OTP after initiating signup on their phone number (confirm signup API call)
3. User is redirected to the sign-in page where he/she enters their email and password registered with us. (sign in API call)
4. User receives an OTP again for authentication of their sign-in. (confirm sign-in API call)

Now, this process goes smoothly. The user gets confirmed and we get an active session for the current User. We get the current user ID through API

**Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser()**

But,

If the user logs out successfully using Amplify.Auth.logout() and try to get back in through the sign-in process (step 3 and 4), we get the following error:

**could not find 'Data'. the token is not a base64 encoded string**

We decoded that the error is being generated in AWSMobileClientExtensions class, but we are not able to identify the source of the error. Please help.